# How to call onUpdate of an appwidget from another widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

In my app I have got two different appwidgets.
Both show and edit the same value.

Both widgets are working fine.
My question is: how can I call the `onUpdate` of the second widget when I edited the value in the first one?
Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using different broadcasts for each widget.
This should be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29)

Call the `updateAppWidget` method of the `AppWidgetManager` passing in the Widget ID of the widget you want to update and the `RemoteViews` to update it to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, but I dont have the RemoteViews of the second widget in my first one.

Comment: Then you need to work out a way to get them. Abstract out the code that creates them so that it is accessible from either widget